# Applovin how to initialize sdk in Android

Tags: android, react-native, applovin

I am trying to initialize the applovin sdk for my react-native app per these instructions: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/mediation/applovin#step_3_import_the_applovin_sdk_and_adapter

On step 3, I am not sure how exactly to use the code `AppLovinSdk.initializeSdk(context);`. I put it in my MainActivity.java onCreate method, but I get a cannot find symbol error since AppLovinSdk is not defined. What exactly am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> AppLovinSdk is not defined

Then import it using this line

```
import com.applovin.sdk.AppLovinSdk;
```

But, you really should be using an `Application` class's `onCreate` rather than an Activity since that SDK would be global to the app, rather than per-Activity.